# Retrieve Hierarchical Data from MySql database

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, tree

This is my Mysql Database

```
╔════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║ Parent_ID ║
╠════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║         0 ║
╠════╬═══════════╣
║  2 ║         1 ║
╠════╬═══════════╣
║  3 ║         1 ║
╠════╬═══════════╣
║  4 ║         3 ║
╠════╬═══════════╣
║  5 ║         4 ║
╚════╩═══════════╝
```

What I want to achieve :

**When user search for *ID 1* , I want to get all those element whose *Parent_ID* is 1 and also all those IDs whose  have *1* as their parent or  grand parent or great grand parent and so on.**

**OR Simply all descendants of ID 1.**

**Example :**

1. if user search for 1, the algorithm should give result
       {2,3,4,5} -- 4,5 because  1 is their great grand parent.
2. if user search for 2, the algorithm should give empty result { } as no
   element have 2 as a Parent_ID
3. if user search for 3, the algorithm should give result    {4,5} -- 5 because 3 is its grand parent.

**What is the good way of saving and retrieving these type of data from database?**

**I am using Java and MySQL**.

Thanks.

Comment: This question in it's present form is a bit too broad. I recommend reading this: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @DavidWallace ... or 4 for that matter.

Comment: @DavidWallace OP didn't know it has to be recursive, hence the question

Comment: @DavidWallace 5 appers because 1 is great grand parent of 5 as (1->2,3), (3->4), (4->5). Hence 1 is great grand parent of 5.

Comment: @DavidWallace intend of OP is to retrieve all the descendants.

Comment: Is there any better way of storing this type of data.

Comment: @PCP if you always query for the root parent, store it in another column (eg: Root_Parent_Id), and you can get all rows with a single query. You can also check this link to go more in depth: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/anthonybloesch/2006/02/15/hierarchies-trees-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: @Joanvo Could u please explain little bit or if u could write answer it will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your data model, you can't do it in a single SQL query, since you need an unknown level of recursion. You need to create a function or stored procedure to iterate over the results of subsequent queries.

This answer may help you:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query

**[Edit]**

If you always query for a root parent (i.e. a row that may have children but has no parent), you can store that id in each row and query by that column:

```
╔════╦═══════════╦════════════════╗
║ ID ║ Parent_ID ║ Root_Parent_ID ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
║  1 ║         0 ║              1 ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
║  2 ║         1 ║              1 ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
║  3 ║         1 ║              1 ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
║  4 ║         3 ║              1 ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
║  5 ║         4 ║              1 ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
║  6 ║         0 ║              6 ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
║  7 ║         6 ║              6 ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
║  8 ║         7 ║              6 ║
╚════╩═══════════╩════════════════╝
```

Then you can just query: 
`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Root_Parent_ID = 1`

Otherwise, I recommend you to go more in depth on how to store this data more efficiently: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/anthonybloesch/2006/02/15/hierarchies-trees-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: thank you for taking out your time for answering the question.

Comment: at the time of inserting data into the sql table, 

I only have two information ID and Parent_ID. So are you suggesting, I create a Root_Parent_ID column and insert Root_Parent_ID during the time of creation of every row.

Comment: and how to get descendants of element lets say ID = 3. i.e {4,5} as {3->4, 4->5}. While getting the list of descendants of 3, I don't want  list of its parents, grand parents.

Comment: For each row, set root_parent_id equal to its parent root_parent_id